# Cyclomatic Generics Code Design

Tags: java, generics

Trying to speak abstract:
I try to design a generic pattern for a network of Components and directed Connectors. All Componenents are connected by Connectors.
So, with no loss of generality, imagining a chain (very simple net) of Components and Connectors we have something like this:
CompA -> ConnectorAB -> CompB -> ConnectorBC -> CompC ...et cetera

As the the Connectors should be actual objects holding with some properties and functions i cannot just implement something like a double chained list of Componenents.

The Components hold theier input- and output-connectors in a list and the connector hold their source- and target-component.
I give you one example-run of mine:

```
interface Component<In extends Connector, Out extends Connector> { List<In> getIns();...}

interface Connector<S extends Component, T extends Component> { S getSource();...}

interface CompA<In extends Connector<?, CompA>, Out extends Connector<CompA, ?>> extends Component<In, Out> {}

interface CompB<In extends Connector<?, CompB>, Out extends Connector<CompB, ?>> extends Component<In, Out> {}

interface A_A extends Connector<CompA, CompA> {}

interface A_B extends Connector<CompA, CompB> {}
```

Problems:

i.) Cyclomatic generic depedencies: i could nest the generics infinitely (`Component<Connector<Component.......>>>`), instead i use raw types, which is fine, but it seems to be messy anyway.

ii.) What i want to express with `CompA<In extends Connector<?, CompA>, Out extends Connector<CompA, ?>>` is, that my CompA knows that it is connected to a Connector aiming at a CompA. Obviously thats not what i am doing syntactically.

iii.)
`A_A aa;
aa.getSource(); //gives me a CompA, thats great.
aa.getSource().getIns(); //gives me a List of raw Connectors, but i would like to have a list of partially defined connectors, they know they are referencing a compA
aa.getSource().getIns().get(0).getTarget() // should give me a compA`
Written my code as it is, it is obvious that this doesnt work as i want it, however i thought ´aa.getSource().getIns();´ could work as the the In-Type is at least a Connector right?

I am asking for suggestions to implement this pattern (so to say, correct my code!). It has to be in java, but i dont have to use only java-generics. If you can accomplish this abstract pattern with non-java-generic patterns it might be fine (a pattern based on other java-language-features, or OO-patterns).

I guess i missed a lot of information, so please ask for it if something is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following will model your requirements best. You may still hit several variance and/or erasure issues. If you do, I would advise you to drop generics entirely rather than resorting to raw types.

```
interface Component<SELF extends Component<SELF>> { Set<Connector<?, SELF>> getIns();...}

interface Connector<SOURCE extends Component<SOURCE>, DESTINATION extends Component<DESTINATION>> { SOURCE getSource();...}

interface CompA extends Component<CompA> {}

interface CompB extends Component<CompB> {}

interface A_A extends Connector<CompA, CompA> {}

interface A_B extends Connector<CompA, CompB> {}
```

Comment: +1, this is exactly what I was thinking of as well :)

Comment: i had to implement a little before judging, but it is perfect! thank you very much and may i ask you how you came up with it? it just came to your mind instantly or is it actually a pattern that was already used anywhere?

Comment: @user2504380 The self type pattern (`Foo<S extends Foo<S>>`, also known as F-bounded quantification) is a fairly common pattern. Once you have that the rest just falls into place. So, yes, when I read your requirements, the solution did come to my mind instantly; but now that you know the self type pattern, it will to yours too. ;)